Finding a function $\omega(x)$ such that the following inequality holds:
I have recently encountered the following inequality problem that has been quite perplexing:
$$\int_{0}^{\infty} f(x)\omega(x)\mathrm{d}x\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{f(x)}{\omega^{2}(x)}\mathrm{d}x\leq C\int_{0}^{\infty}f(x)\mathrm{d}x\int_{0}^{\infty}f(x)\mathrm{d}x$$
for some $C>0$ a constant, with $ f(x) $ being a bounded function taking values in $[0,1]$ and the weight function $ w(x) $ also taking values in $[0,1]$. What conditions must $ w(x) $ satisfy for the above inequality to hold true?
Maybe the Holder inequality could be used ?
Your valuable suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
Have a wonderful day, everyone!

The inequality must hold for ALL $f:(0,+\infty)\to[0,1]$ bounded?

Maybe it should be

Let $E:=\{f:(0,\infty)\to[0,1]\text{ is Lebesgue-measurable}\ \vert\ \int_0^\infty f(x)dx<\infty\}$ and let $\omega:(0,\infty)\to[0,1]$ Lebesgue-measurable.
We may as well assume $\omega>0$ Lebesgue-almost everywhere, for if $\omega(x)=0$ on $(a,b)$ with $0<a<b<\infty$, then taking $f(x)=(b-a)^{-1}\mathrm{1}_{(a,b)}(x)\in E$ leads to $\int_0^\infty f(x)\omega(x)dx=0$ while $\int_0^\infty\frac{f(x)}{\omega(x)^2}dx=\infty$ (so that the left-hand side product in the desired inequality does not make any sense).
Consider the following function:
$$\Lambda_\omega:E\ni f\longmapsto\int_0^\infty f(x)\omega(x)dx\int_0^\infty\frac{f(x)}{\omega(x)^2}dx\in(0,\infty)$$
Observe that, since $f\geq0$ for all $f\in E$, $\int_0^\infty f(x)dx=0$ only happens for $f=0$ Lebesgue-almost everywhere, so that we can ignore this trivial case below.
Notice also that $\Lambda_\omega$ is a quadratic form on $E$ so that we can equivalently prove that $\Lambda_\omega$ is bounded on $F:=\{f\in E\ \vert\ \|f\|_{L^1(0,\infty)}=1\}$, for if $f\in E\setminus\{0\}$, then defining $g:=f/\|f\|_{L^1(0,\infty)}\in F$, we have:
$$\Lambda_\omega(f)=\Lambda_\omega(\|f\|_{L^1(0,\infty)}g)=\|f\|_{L^1(0,\infty)}^2\Lambda_\omega(g)$$
We shall prove the following result:

The function $\Lambda_\omega:F\to(0,\infty)$ is bounded if and only if the following holds: If there exist $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ as well as Lebesgue-measurable sets $(A_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ such that $a_n\in[0,1]$, $A_n\subset(0,\infty)$ and
$$\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}a_n\int_{A_n}\frac{dx}{\omega(x)^2}=\infty,$$
then
$$\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}a_n|A_n|=\infty.$$

Assume first that $$\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}a_n\int_{A_n}\frac{dx}{\omega(x)^2}=\infty,\qquad\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}a_n|A_n|<\infty.$$
Put:
$$f:=\frac{\displaystyle\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}a_n\mathrm{1}_{A_n}}{\displaystyle\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}a_n|A_n|}.$$
Clearly $\|f\|_{L^1(0,\infty)}=1$ so that $f\leq 1$ Lebesgue-almost surely; up to modifying $f$ on a set of Lebesgue-measure $0$, we can assume $f\leq1$, hence $f\in F$. We have:
$$\int_0^\infty\frac{f(x)}{\omega(x)^2}dx=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}a_n\int_{A_n}\frac{dx}{\omega(x)^2}=\infty.$$
As $f,\omega>0$ Lebesgue-almost everywhere, we deduce that $\Lambda_\omega(f)=\infty$.
Assume now that $$\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}a_n\int_{A_n}\frac{dx}{\omega(x)^2}=\infty\qquad\implies\qquad\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}a_n|A_n|=\infty.$$
If $f\in F$ is such that $\Lambda_\omega(f)=\infty$, then we can write (as $f$ is Lebesgue-measurable):
$$f:=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}a_n\mathrm{1}_{A_n}.$$
Since
$$\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}a_n\int_{A_n}\frac{dx}{\omega(x)^2}=\int_0^\infty\frac{f(x)}{\omega(x)^2}dx=\infty$$
we have by hypothesis:
$$\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}a_n|A_n|=\infty.$$
Yet:
$$\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}a_n|A_n|=\int_0^\infty f(x)dx=1.$$

Remarks: The above condition may be not very handy in practice. The following sufficient condition could help then:
If $x\mapsto\omega(x)^{-2}\in L^p(0,\infty)$ for some $p\in[1,\infty]$, then by Hölder's inequality:
$$\Lambda_\omega(f)\leq\|f\|_{L^q(0,\infty)}^{1/q}\|\omega^{-2}\|_{L^p(0,\infty)}^{1/p}\qquad\forall f\in F$$
where $\|f\|_{L^q(0,\infty)}^{1/q}\leq\|f\|_{L^1(0,\infty)}^{1/q}=1$ as $f\in[0,1]$. When $p=\infty$, $\omega(x)\geq\varepsilon>0$ for Lebesgue-almost every $x\in(0,\infty)$, then:
$$\Lambda_\omega(f)\leq\varepsilon^{-2}\qquad\forall f\in F.$$

Thank you very much for your generous response! Wishing you success in everything!

At the same time, I would like to ask if the direction of the above inequality can be reversed?
In other words, if there exists some $\omega$ satisfying that
$$\int_{0}^{\infty} f(x)\omega(x)\mathrm{d}x\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{f(x)}{\omega^{2}(x)}\mathrm{d}x\geq C\int_{0}^{\infty}f(x)\mathrm{d}x\int_{0}^{\infty}f(x)\mathrm{d}x$$
Many thanks for your thoughtful and informative reply.

@LZ981ko I realize that in my proof above, I show that $\Lambda_\omega(f)$ is bounded, but the bound may depend on $f$, which is maybe not what you are looking for. I will have some thinking about this, as well as your additional question. I will come back to you if I have anything.

Thank you very much for your constructive feedback. I will also give this more in-depth thought in the near future.
Wishing you a wonderful day!
